# On the solvability of the negative Pell equation $x^2-2py^2 = -1$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, class-field-theory, pell-type-equations

Given prime $p=8n+1$. Then

$$x^2-2py^2 = -1\tag1$$

is ***not solvable*** for,

$$p_1= 17, 73, 89, 97, 193, 233, 241, 257, 281, 337, 353, 401, 433, 449, 577, 593,601, 617, 641,\dots$$

but ***is  solvable*** for,

$$p_2= 41, 113, 137, 313, 409, 457, 521, 569, 761, 809, 857, 953, 1129, 1201, 1321, 1601,\dots$$

Compare to the primes of form $p=u^2+32v^2$ ([A105389](http://oeis.org/A105389)):

$$p_3 = 41, 113, 137, \color{brown}{257}, 313,  \color{brown}{337},  \color{brown}{353}, 409, 457, 521, 569,  \color{brown}{577},  \color{brown}{593}, 761, 809, 857,  \color{brown}{881}, 953, \dots$$

(Also, $p_3$ has *class number* $h(-p)$ divisible by 8.)

> **Q:  Is $p_2$ a subset of $p_3$?**
>
> (Equivalently, for $p=8n+1$, is it true that a necessary but not sufficient condition such that $(1)$ is solvable is that $p = u^2+32v^2$?)

I have checked that all solvable $p = 8n+1 \leq 18089$ has the form $u^2+32v^2$, but I don't know if ***all*** solvable $p$ have that form.

$\color{blue}{Edit}$: (In response to Jagy's answer.) The primes of form $p=u^2+64v^2$ ([A014754](http://oeis.org/A014754)) are,

$$p_4 = 73, 89, 113, 233, 257, 281, 337, 353, 577, 593, 601, 617, 881, 937, 1033, 1049, 1097\dots$$

but neither $p_1$ nor $p_2$ is a subset of $p_4$. However, the primes of form
$p=u^2+64v^2=16n+9$,

$$p_5 = 73, 89, 233, 281, 601, 617, 937, 1033, 1049, 1097,\dots$$

as a result of Dirichlet, is unsolvable and so is a subset of $p_1$.

Comment: It's not the divide by 8. And the decomposition into the sum of squares. What is not satisfied, the formula which led? It is enough to consider the equivalent form.

Comment: @individ: The expression $h(-d)$ means "_class number of_ $-d$". [For example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=NumberFieldClassNumber%5BSqrt%5B-953%5D%5D) $h(-953) = 32$, hence is divisible by 8. I don't think one can answer this question by obvious elementary means.

Comment: Still I do not understand. The formula in General.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1048219___2  To convert your equation to consider all of the possible equivalent forms. It will give an idea of how the sum of squares.  What is the meaning of this? If all the problems are solved by one formula.

Comment: do you mean that the red primes are exactly those for which h(-d) is not divisible by 8 ?

Comment: just so you guys know, the second list is the list of primes for which $-1$, $2$, and $1\pm \sqrt 2$ are squares mod $p$

Comment: @mercio: The complement of $p_3$ with $p_2$ starts as, $$p_6 = \color{brown}{257,313,353,577,593,881,\dots}$$ There are the unsolvable $p=u^2+32v^2$. Are you saying that _all_ $p_6$ do not pass the test $-1,\,2$ and $1\pm\sqrt{2}$ as squares mod $p$?

Answer (score 3):

at least a start: for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ there is a trichotomy due to Dirichlet, pages 164-165 of Buell: exactly one of
$$ A: \; 2 x^2 - p y^2 = 1,   $$
$$ B: \; 2 x^2 - p y^2 = -1,   $$
$$ C: \;2 x^2 - p y^2 = -2,   $$
is solvable in integers. Your $(1)$ is the third choice $C$, as $y$ is then even. [I'm afraid this material relates more clearly to](http://oeis.org/A014754) $p = u^2 + 64 v^2,$ as the results are

If A is solvable, then C is not solvable and $p \equiv 1 \pmod {16}.$

If B is solvable, then C is not solvable and $p = u^2 + 64 v^2$

If $p \equiv 9 \pmod {16}$ and $2$ is not a fourth power, then C is solvable. Note $p \neq u^2 + 64 v^2$

These are the primes $9 \pmod {16}$ represented by $4 u^2 + 4uv + 17 v^2,$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./primego
Input three coefficients a b c for positive f(x,y)= a x^2 + b x y + c y^2 
4 4 17
Discriminant  -256

Modulus for arithmetic progressions? 
16
Maximum number represented?         1700
          p          mod 16
          17           1
          41           9
          97           1
         137           9
         193           1
         241           1
         313           9
         401           1
         409           9
         433           1
         449           1
         457           9
         521           9
         569           9
         641           1
         673           1
         761           9
         769           1
         809           9
         857           9
         929           1
         953           9
         977           1
        1009           1
        1129           9
        1297           1
        1321           9
        1361           1
        1409           1
        1489           1
        1657           9
        1697           1
........................
```

A little more: we can write $p = u^2 + 32 v^2$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and there are four distinct roots to
$$  z^4 - 2 z^2 + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod p. $$ 
We can write $p = u^2 + 64 v^2$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ and there are four distinct roots to
$$  z^4 -  2 \equiv 0 \pmod p. $$
This is from the final table in Liu and Williams, about 1994.

Comment: I have simplified my question. Based on your references, is $p_2$ a subset of $p_3$? (The sequences are defined in my post.)

Comment: It seems the trichotomy has a result on the special case $p=16n+9$. But I think for the general $p=8n+1$, whether $p_2$ is a subset of $p_3$ is a good question to ask.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII, my guess would be that there is a pretty good description of your primes in terms of algebraic number theory, but not necessarily in terms of binary quadratic forms. Collected works of Dirichlet, maybe

Comment: +1 for Dirichlet's result that if $p=u^2+64v^2 = 16n+9$, then $x^2-2py^2 = -1$ is unsolvable.

Comment: For the sequence ([A133204](http://oeis.org/A133204)) of general prime $p$ such that $x^2-2py^2=-1$ is solvable, I came across this paper, [The quadratic form $x^2-2py^2$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X78900033), which might be interesting reading.